# How can I use awk to sort a list by numbers that are surrounded by two common delimiters?

Tags: unix, awk

E.g. here is a sample of the file below. I'd like to sort all the lines in order of Corr, where the delimiter before the number is "=" and the delimiter after the number is "at".

```
PrecipNH0to90vsNetNH0to90 Corr = -0.5073 at Net Leading Precip by -1 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetSH0to90 Corr = -0.6498 at Net Leading Precip by 2 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetHemDif0to90 Corr = 0.66939 at Net Leading Precip by 9 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetGlobal0to90 Corr = -0.66036 at Net Leading Precip by 0 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetAsymIndex0to90 Corr = 0.65726 at Net Leading Precip by 0 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetNH0to14 Corr = -0.46212 at Net Leading Precip by -2 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetSH0to14 Corr = -0.70731 at Net Leading Precip by 4 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetHemDif0to14 Corr = 0.70494 at Net Leading Precip by 8 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetGlobal0to14 Corr = -0.66121 at Net Leading Precip by 0 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetAsymIndex0to14 Corr = 0.64884 at Net Leading Precip by 8 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetNH14to30 Corr = 0.46232 at Net Leading Precip by 10 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetSH14to30 Corr = -0.80044 at Net Leading Precip by 2 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetHemDif14to30 Corr = 0.74188 at Net Leading Precip by 9 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetGlobal14to30 Corr = -0.62494 at Net Leading Precip by 2 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetAsymIndex14to30 Corr = 0.46709 at Net Leading Precip by 5 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetNH30to49 Corr = 0.49765 at Net Leading Precip by 10 Months Time Lag
PrecipNH0to90vsNetSH30to49 Corr = 0.21001 at Net Leading Precip by 10 Months Time Lag
```

I know that the file could be organized a lot more neatly when I printed it out from Matlab, but I'm still curious about this as a general case.

Comment: Looks to me that the delimiter is SPACE and you want to sort on column 4 using the sort command, not awk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sort -nk4,4 <filename>
```

Or if you REALLY love awk:

```
awk '{print $4}' <filename> | sort -n
```

sort -nk4 = sort numerically (n) on the 4th field only (k4,4)

awk - {print $4} = print the 4th field only.  Awk automatically splits by spaces.

Finally, just for fun I did a version that uses ONLY awk to implement it's own bubble sort. :-)  It could probably be a little bit cleaner, but it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Script to sort a data file based on column 4
{
  # Read every line into an array
  line[NR]  = $0
  # Also save the sort column so we don't have to split the line again repeatedly
  value[NR] = $4
}
END { # sort it with bubble sort
  do {
    haschanged = 0
    for(i=1; i < NR; i++) {
      if ( value[i] > value[i+1] ) {
        # Swap adjacent lines and values.
        t = line[i]
        line[i] = line[i+1]
        line[i+1] = t
        t = value[i]
        value[i] = value[i+1]
        value[i+1] = t
        haschanged = 1
      }
    }
  } while ( haschanged == 1 )
  # Print out the result.
  for(i=1; i <= NR; i++) {
    print line[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: `sort -k4` doesn't sort based on the 4th field (only) - it sorts FROM the 4th field THROUGH THE END OF THE LINE. Because of `-n` (numerical sorting), it _happens_ to be limited to the 4th field in this case, because parsing the remainder of the line is only performed as far as the string is recognized as a _number_. Generally, to truly only sort by field 4, use `sort -k4,4`. With GNU `sort` you can see this behavior in action with `sort --debug -k4` vs. `sort --debug -k4,4`. `sort` is a strange beast.